# Node.JS JavaScript PeerJS ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, peerjs

I'm trying to build a simple peer to peer image sharing demo app using Node.JS and PeerJS.

But when I try to run the app, I get an error `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`.

This is a node.js backend app so I don't get why PeerJS is requesting to identify the navigator.

Could you please help me spot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const Peer = require('peerjs');

const app = express();

const port = 9500;

const sender = new Peer('sender', { 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: port, 
    path: '/' 
});

const receiver = new Peer('receiver', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: port,
    path: '/'
});
     
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/send', (req, res) => {
    ...
    ...
    
    let image = readDataset();
    const conn = sender.connect('receiver');

    conn.on('open',()=> {
        conn.send({
            photo: image,
        });

        res.status(200).send("Image sent.");
    });
});

app.get('/receive', (req, res) => {

    receiver.on('connection', conn => {
        conn.on('data', data => {
          ...
          ...  
          res.status(200).send("Image received and saved.");
        });
    });

});

// set the app to listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Is peer.js a node package or a browser one? Their description _”PeerJS wraps the browser's WebRTC implementation”_ makes me think it’s browser only.

Comment: have you checked this issue? https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/819

Comment: `new Peer({..` can only be called on clientside

Comment: @Georgy Helpful but problem persists.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm used Node.JS NPM package 'peerjs'. npm install peerjs

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi Official NPM documentation says otherwise. https://www.npmjs.com/package/peerjs

Comment: @Vakindu using `npm` doesn't mean it will work with node. The docs you linked to even has a "browser support" section, further implying it being browser only.